# Setting up local administrator accounts that still require a domain administrator for certain tasks

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, user-accounts

Having started in a new place recently, I've been tasked with setting up 2 new workstations, however I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly how the workstations here were configured in the past, and no one seems to be entirely sure.

The existing workstations (laptops), are all set up to be part of the domain here, but the users log on locally, and there are no accounts from the domain that are actually added to the workstations. If you use Windows utility to view the accounts on the computer, there is simply the one local account which is a member of the Administrator group. However, if you try to take any action that requires admin privileges on these workstations, you will have to input the domain administrator credentials in order to gain permission.

With the new workstations however, if I simply join the domain, the local users (which appear to be identical to those of the older workstations) do not require domain administrator credentials for anything - why is that?

I'd like to figure out how the accounts on the newer and the older workstations differ, but I'm a little lost at the moment.

Comment: Can you try inputting local administrator credentials instead on the old machine? Apparently there is difference in level of User Account Control sensitivity. Also, I think I've seen a Group Policy that would ask full credentials instead of prompting for yes or no when it comes to elevation.

Comment: Hey Grigory, inputting local adminstrator credentials on the old machine doesn't work for authentication (I just tried), it also specifically specifies, underneath the login box, that it is the domain which requires the login. Also on the new machine, it does not even prompt for yes or no, it simply allows me to take whatever action I want, without requiring any elevation whatsoever.

Comment: Old machine: prepend login with dot backslash .\administrator

Comment: Compare user account control level on both machines, new one has higher level, most probably.

Comment: I feel absolutely silly now, you're brilliant and totally right, it had to do with UAC all along. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it is a very powerful but largely underestimated technology. Three cheers for Windows Vista!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is difference in level of User Account Control sensitivity.

Also, I think I've seen a Group Policy that would ask full credentials instead of prompting for yes or no when it comes to elevation.

As per comments.